# Why chemical energy is doing the work on the electrons to move them from cathode to anode and not some kind of force?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, electrochemistry

We say that in an electrolytic cell the redox reactions occuring on the electrodes are exothermic and that chemical energy does work on electrons to move them from cathode to anode and this work done is stored as energy in the electrons.

Doubt—> From the above concept it is clear that chemical energy did work on the electrons to move them from cathode to anode. But the electrodes create a potential difference and if there is a potential difference then there should be an electric field also going from cathode to anode therefore electrons coming into that electric field will experience a force towards cathode but to move them towards anode, one has to apply force in the opposite direction of electric field and that force should do the work done and that work done should be stored in electrons but this doesn't happen in reality. My question is why does this doesn't happen in reality, why there is no force acting on the electrons even though there is a potential difference and hence an electric field, why chemical energy is doing the work?
Pls clear my doubt.

Comment: Electrolytes are electrical insulators. The current in an electrolytic cell is carried by ions, not electrons.

Comment: The potential difference is applied so as to withdraw the electrons from the anodeand drive them to the cathode. You seemed to imply the contrary but I am not sure I understood what you meant

Comment: Potentials and forces are just different perspectives on the same thing: the driving of physical changes in a system.

Comment: Barbaud Julien....yes the potential difference allows the movement of charges from anode to cathode in external circuit but I wanted to know that in the internal circuit that is the cell how does the movement occur from cathode to anode...the reason my teacher gave was that the chemical reactions occuring on the electrodes liberate chemical energy and that chemical energy does work on the charges to move against the potential gradient and then get stored as work done on the charges. But my doubt was that if there is a potential difference then there should be an electric field and that

Comment: @BarbaudJulien continued here.... electric field will apply force on the negative charges to come towards cathode but in order to take those charges towards anode there should be a force applied in the opposite direction of the electric field and hence that force will do work on the charges and that work done will be stored in the charges...in short I wanted to ask that if there is a potential difference then why there is no force which should do the work? Why instead of a force against the electric field, the chemical energy is doing the work on charges.

Comment: @John Doty Why do you say that electrolytes are insulators? They are ionic conductors but not insulators.

Comment: @nasu They are insulators for electrons.

Comment: This not the meaning of electrical insulator. Electrical current can go through electrolytes so they are electricl conductors. And it can be a net transport of electrons through electrolytes too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For electrolytic cells:

- The charge carriers are not electrons.
- The transport mechanism for conductive electrolytic solutions is not from the electric field generated between electrodes.

The mechanism for generating current in an electrolytic cell is very different than conduction in a wire. The biggest difference is that the charge carriers in wire are electrons. The charge carriers in electrolytes are not electrons. The charge carriers are the dissolved ions in solution. These ions act as a source/sink for electrons at the electrode surface. The ionization of these carriers occurs at the redox potential which is the energy to add or remove electrons from the ion. This reduction/oxidation reaction is the chemical energy and occurs at a given voltage. An IV plot of the reaction would show a current peak at the redox potential.

How do the ions in solution migrate to the electrode? An intuitive assumption( based on solid state physics) would be that the electric field generated by the potential difference between electrodes drives ions to the electrode surface for redox. But the electrolyte is a liquid ( the ions move around to redistribute the charge to minimize the field ) and conductive so the field generated by the electrodes is minimal and contributes in only a secondary manner. The primary transport mechanism is diffusion. As ions reach the electrode surface a reaction takes place and there is a depletion region near the electrode that is absent of ions. Ions diffuse into this region at a rate based on the concentration gradient. This occurs at both anode and cathode.

So there is no applied force to move the electrons through solution. It's done by diffusion.

Comment: and what about the chemical energy which the charges get from the redox reactions at electrodes  and that energy allows the charges to move towards anode and get stored in the charges. Pls explain.

Comment: If the movement is occurring by diffusion then what is the role of that chemical energy....if chemical energy doesn't play any role in the movement then how does the cell convert chemical energy into electrical energy?? Pls explain

Comment: An electrolytic cell uses electrical energy to drive a chemical reaction. The chemical reaction is the reduction or oxidation of a dissolved ion in solution. The electrodes provide the potential and the electrons. In a conductive aqueous solution, the primary transport mechanism is diffusion not the electric field. This is a topic in electrochemistry and you may need to read an introductory text to understand what's going on.

Comment: Looks like my answer has a mistake in it. Stevan's describes transport of ions better.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban, ok I guess I will understand things more clearly while studying electrochemistry...thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the same thing can be described by two different concepts.

If a force is applied to a particle, the particle speeds up and gains kinetic energy. A speeding particle can coast up a hill, losing kinetic energy and gaining potential energy. Gravity acts against the upward velocity component, so the particle slows down. You can describe what happens with either force or energy.

Suppose two blocks slide past each other. The force of friction opposes the direction of motion, so the blocks slow down. Under a microscope, atoms from the two different blocks collide with each other, and often gain kinetic energy. Atom bonds are electromagnetic forces that can be approximated as springs. So the atoms begin vibrating hard than they had been, trading kinetic and potential energy back and forth. From a macroscopic point of view, we do not track the motion of atoms. We characterize their average vibrational energy as heat. So you can describe this energy as either kinetic/potential energy or heat.

Chemical energy is like this. Quantum mechanics is needed for a good description, but atomic bonds are caused by forces between atoms. The forces are attractive when atoms are too far apart, and repulsive when too close. Atoms lose potential energy when they come together to form a bond. Sometimes they can lose even more energy by rearranging themselves into different bonds. From a macroscopic point of view, we describe the total energy gained and lost as chemical energy. From a microscopic point of view, it is potential energy.

An electrolytic cell contains charged ions. Electric forces cause them to be attracted to the electrodes, where they undergo reactions. You can see how many atoms react and describe this as chemical energy.

You can also measure the flowing charges that come out of these reactions. You can measure the energy by voltage (Joules per coulomb of charge). Energy is conserved. You find that the chemical energy lost is the same as the electrical energy gained.

Comment: @mmesser314...so there is no problem if I describe all things in terms of chemical energy or in terms of force.

Comment: Use the easiest. If you know the electric field and distance between the electrodes, use the force. If you know the voltage and current, use them. If you know the reactions and reaction rate, use them.

Comment: Can you please explain that how can one demonstrate conversion of chemical energy to electrical energy by a cell by using the concept of 'force'....I will be very grateful if you will explain that to me.

Comment: In a conductive solution, the primary transport mechanism of ions in solution is diffusion. Not the electric field.